# Exclude single executable from path

Tags: windows-10, command-line, git, environment-variables, path

I have a small problem with my path environment on windows 10.

I'm running CLion, which uses CMake, and it spits out this error:

```
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.
```

Now, I consciously added git to my path so that I can keep using it from the command line, so I was wondering if there's a way to exclude just `sh.exe` from my path as I'd much prefer to keep using git from cmd.

I'm also not quite sure if git uses `sh.exe` so I'm reluctant to delete it outright.

The environment variable itself is:

`C:/Program Files/Git/bin`

Running windows 10 Build 17134

If there's a way to configure CMake/CLion to use a shell without using (that part of) the path env variable I'd be glad to hear that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot exclude a single file from path.

The best that you can do is to have your default path not include `git` and create a batch file which allows you to use the git shell and put that in your path.

That way, you can invoke `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe` from, let’s say, `git.bat` which ***is*** in your path, but CLion won’t complain because `sh.exe` isn’t in your path.

Comment: What if `git.exe` requires `sh.exe` to be in the path as well? If that is the case, this solution won't work. I am also unaware of a way to comprehensively check if it's the case, if you know a way I'd gladly check and report back if this solution could work :)

Comment: A very good point. I guess that you can only suck it & see. Give it a try and let us know. If that won't work, I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and unless I get other suggestions I'll mark this as accepted